# The findAll method in Neo4jRepository returns null for nested attributes

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

The structure of my program is:

- School

  - Board

    - Grade

      - Subject

        - Topic

School.java

```java
@NodeEntity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class School extends Entity {
    private String name;
    @Relationship(type = "UNDER")
    private Board board;
    private String address;
    private String phone;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "School{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", board=" + board +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Board.java

```java
@NodeEntity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Board extends Entity {
    private String name;
    @Relationship(type = "HAS")
    private List<Grade> grades;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Board{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", grades=" + grades +
                '}';
    }
}
```

SchoolRepository.java

```java
@Repository
public interface SchoolRepository extends Neo4jRepository<School, Long> {
}
```

It's a spring-boot project and I have the relevant controllers and services.

The problem is that the `schoolRepository.findAll()` returns null for the `grades` present in the `board`.

However the complete data is displayed in the database.

Output I'm getting on my swagger:

```
[
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Bishops",
    "board": {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "CBSE",
      "grades": null
    },
    "address": "Nagpur",
    "phone": "1234567891"
  },
  {
    "id": 15111,
    "name": "Conrads",
    "board": {
      "id": 15132,
      "name": "ICSE",
      "grades": null
    },
    "address": "Agra",
    "phone": "789456123"
  }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the default depth for `findAll` is 1. So the `School` and it's `Board` are loaded but not the `Grades` of the `Board` as the Grades are at depth 2 from the school.

If you pass the depth parameter of 2 to `findAll`, the grades will be loaded.

Comment: Do the derived functions support the depth or do we need to write a custom query?

Comment: I used the @Depth annotation and it worked. Thank you.